# Allied Telsey Switch 3 step SSH login

Tags: networking, ssh, authentication, switching

[image: Putty login]

Helo,
i have Allied Telesis GS 8000/48 switch in my network.
When i login over SSH I first need to enter "LOGIN AS:" part. In this part i can enter anything i want. After "Login as:" I am entering username and password.
When i login over Telnet I am directly entering username and password. On Telnet there is NO "Login as:" part.

How can i remove "Login as:" part on SSH access?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

ssh -l username hostaddress
Tells ssh to login with the given username

Comment: Sorry, i cant make this work. I want to make RANCID automatic switch backup, and this step where switch wants the "Login as:" part to be entered is making me problems. I can have username and password on RANCID SSH login, but not the "Login as" part.